# about S3 web hosting index setting does not work

Tags: amazon-s3, dns

I'm using S3 web hosting for host website.

I want to make setting for , 
if user access mydomain/ then response mydomain/index.html

On S3 console I set Index Document: index.html in webhosting section.
but it doesn't work well.

now I access to mydomain/" then response is 403(access denied) status code.
if I access to mydomain/index.html" then index.html returned(works well)

I'm not using Route53 for DNS, I'm using my domain register's DNS.
I set cname recode.

Please give me some advise.
That's very helpful for me.

Thanks.